# Can a long running redis job yield the worker and requeue itself?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

Is it possible for a job to yield the worker and put itself back to the end of the queue?

The jobs in a redis queue are processed sequentially and a long-running job might be hogging the cpu.  Is there a pattern for it to decide it has consumed enough time and should yield to other items in the queue?

I note that there is provision to `requeue_job` in the `rq` implementation; if the job has "failed".  Perhaps that is a way to hack up a way to do it?

Or perhaps there is a job timeout that can be leveraged?
Or is this branch of thinking just another deadend?

Answer (score 1):

There is a job timeout parameter:

```
job = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://stackoverflow.com', timeout=180)
```

The default timeout is 180 if you choose not to set it explicitly.

If the job times out, the job will move to the `failed` queue.

You can later requeue failed jobs:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, get_failed_queue

r = Redis()
failed_queue = get_failed_queue(r)
print failed_queue.count
for job_id in failed_queue.job_ids:
    failed_queue.requeue(job_id)
```